# kubernetes init container for spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to run a spark-submit to the Kubernetes cluster with spark 3.2.1 image and it is working. Now my question is, can I execute an init container along with the spark-submit? What am trying to achieve is that the init container check another service is up or not, is it up then spark-submit will run or it fail.

I can see that a conf parameter "spark.kubernetes.initContainer.image" for spark version 2.3 but not for 3.2.1 (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/running-on-kubernetes.html)

is there any mechanism that I can use to check other services are up or not before I submit a spark job?

I can see init container usage for the spark in the below links but it is not providing an accurate answer

https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/infrastructure/spark/configuration/configure-sidecar-init-containers/
https://doc.lucidworks.com/spark-guide/11153/running-spark-on-kubernetes

any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the best way to submit a spark job is the sparkoperator, more details can be found in the [GitHub link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md#using-init-containers)

There is one option to include an init container and a sidecar container.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if the other service is in the same container or not but the principles are the same. It's covered in the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) and gives this example which defines a simple Pod that has two init containers. The first waits for myservice, and the second waits for mydb. Once both init containers complete, the Pod runs the app container from its spec section.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup myservice.$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done"]
  - name: init-mydb
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup mydb.$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for mydb; sleep 2; done"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding sample spark submit command.
./bin/spark-submit   --master k8s://https://50.1.0.4:6443   --deploy-mode cluster   --name spark-pi   --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark   --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi   --conf spark.executor.instances=1   --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:v3.2.1 --conf local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.2.1.jar 
Here we are passing the image from the command line and not writing any manifest file for spark pod, k8s create the pods

Answer (score 0):

You can define a pod template for your pod

```
 ./bin/spark-submit --master k8s://50.1.0.4:6443 --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:v3.2.1 
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.podTemplateFile=//path/my_pod_template.yaml
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile=//path/my_pod_template.yaml
--conf local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.2.1.jar
```

Note, that a template doesn't have to contain all necessary fields for Spark app to function. It's main purpose, as described in the official [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template) is to:

> Spark users can similarly use template files to define the driver or
> executor pod configurations that Spark configurations do not support.

That means that a lot/most fields will be overridden based on `--conf` values. In my case I didn't want to specify the main container spec, I only needed the `initContainer` to make some init checks. Needless to say, all volumes and env vars which are available to the main container will also be available to the init container without explicitly adding them to the pod template.

**my_pod_template.yaml:** 
something like in Alan's answer

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup myservice.$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done"]
  - name: init-mydb
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup mydb.$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for mydb; sleep 2; done"]
```

**source:** https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it explains a Spark-native way to do it, without k8s operators. I also use the same setup in my project and it works like a charm.